# How to SUM all constant value members on MDX

Tags: database, mdx

How can i sum the values of a constant member on the totalization row. For example, this query:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[department_code] as departments.[department_code].CurrentMember.MEMBER_CAPTION
  MEMBER [Measures].[twelve] as 12
    SELECT 
      {[Measures].[revenue],
 [Measures].[department_code],
 [Measures].[twelve]
  } ON 0,

    departments.[department_code].ALLMEMBERS
    ON 1
    FROM 
      mycube
```

Returns this:

```
NULL    1000    All     12
DEPT1   600     DEPT1   12
DEPT2   400     DEPT2   12
```

The first row, which is the totalization, should return 24 for the last cokumn ([Measure].[twelve]).

How can this be accomplished?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should make the following changes to your constant member

```
MEMBER [Measures].[twelve] 
as 
case 
when departments.[department_code].CurrentMember.MEMBER_CAPTION='All'
then count([Product].[Product].children) * 12 
else
12
end
```

Here is a sample of what you want on Adventure works

```
with member
[Measures].[ProductCode] 
as
[Product].[Product].CurrentMember.MEMBER_CAPTION
member
[Measures].[Constant] 
as
case 
when [Product].[Product].CurrentMember.MEMBER_CAPTION='All Products'
then count([Product].[Product].children) * 12 
else 
12
end

select 
{
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],
[Measures].[ProductCode] ,
[Measures].[Constant] 
} on 0,

[Product].[Product].members
on 1 
from [Adventure Works]
```